# Existence of Orthogonal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$ with a scalar product. Show that $V$ has an orthogonal basis. Furthermore, does the statement valid if $V$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: For the finite case, one can explicitly construct a ONB via Gram-Schmidt.  In the infinitive case Zorn's Lemma garanties only the existence of an ONB.

Comment: How does Zorn's Lemma garanties the existence of ONB? In the proof of existence of any basis of infinite dimensional v.s. we just extend any linearly independent subset of $V$ to the maximal linearly independent subset of $V$.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but they are useless anyhow.  In a Hilbert space one deal with orthonormal systems, that is a set of orthonormal vectors which is dense in the space.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Zorns Lemma guarantees a basis, not necessarily an orthonormal one.