Is the inverse of an orthogonality-preserving bijection $V \to V$ orthogonality-preserving?
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ equipped with non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$. We call a map $f : V \to V$ orthogonality-preserving if
$$\forall v,w\in V: \langle v,w\rangle = 0 \implies \langle f(v), f(w)\rangle = 0.$$
Note that $f$ is not required to be linear.
I wonder if for a bijective orthogonality-preserving map also the direction $\Leftarrow$ is true.
For general orthogonality-preserving maps this property is clearly wrong, a counterexample is given by the all-zero function. But for bijective maps, I could not find a proof neither a counterexample so far.
Remarks

In this setting, any field $F$ and any non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$ are allowed. In particular, there may be isotropic non-zero vectors $v$, meaning that that $\langle v,v\rangle = 0$.
As an example, if $F$ is of characteristic $p \neq 0$, then the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)\in F^p$ is isotropic with respect to the standard scalar product $\langle x,y\rangle = x_1 y_1 + \ldots + x_n y_n$.

In this question, an affirmative answer is given for linear maps and the standard scalar product over $F = \mathbb{R}$. The proof is not directly adoptable to the linear case over a general field $F$ because of the presence of isotropic vectors.

One might also think about the underlying statement of this and this question: Is any (not necessarily linear) orthogonality-preserving map the scalar multiple of a (not necessarily linear) map preserving the scalar product (i.e. $\langle v, w\rangle = \langle f(v), f(w)\rangle$ for all $v,w\in V$, which is stronger than being orthogonality-preserving)?
If so, this would answer my question with "yes".

For the standard scalar product over $F = \mathbb{R}$, any surjective scalar-product-preserving map $f : V \to V$ is linear (even in the infinite dimensional case). This is discussed in the context of this question.

I had asked the question for maps $V \to W$ before, not being aware that this allows easy counterexamples. First I had modified that question, but it was not well received. Hence I followed the suggestion to open a new question.



@AnneBauval Thank you, I will add a pointer. However I'm not sure if the general linear case is obvious (to me). The question (and certainly the answer) you linked appears only to be about the standard scalar product over $\mathbb{R}$. I allow general fields and general non-degenerate symmetric bilinear forms.


I do not understand why, in your 3rd comment, you write "(not necessarily linear)" while linking to a post where the maps are linear 2) Related, though not very helpful.


If the characteristic is $≠2$ (and if I am not wrong!), I can prove that any orthogonality-preserving linear bijection is the scalar multiple of a "scalar product"-preserving one. I use that wlog, $V$ has an orthogonal basis $(u,v)$ and $⟨Tu,Tu⟩≠0$.

In your opinion, should I try to write it as a (generalizing) answer here, or there, or somewhere else?

@AnneBauval Thank your for all the comments and pointers! I've clarified the 3rd comment (no idea how much of wishful thinking that property is...) Concerning your result on linear orthogonality-preserving linear bijections: That's interesting. Should I open a new question tailored for that property? Also, is it clear that an orthogonal basis does always exist in this general setting?

@AnneBauval Concerning the existence of an orthogonal basis, there is this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2011730/61691 without an answer though. I checked Gram-Schmidt: It starts with an arbitrary basis ${v_1,\ldots,v_n}$ and computes an orthogonal basis ${w_1,\ldots,w_n}$ one by one. One will run into trouble as soon as one of the vectors $v_i$ is isotropic. So the question is whether $V$ has any basis ${v_1,\ldots,v_n}$ where all vectors are non-isotropic. My feeling is that this should be true.

Thanks for the link in your last comment. I posted answer there.

Maybe this reference is of some interest https://arxiv.org/abs/2410.08101

@Jordi Thanks. The setting is a bit different: On the one hand they allow infinite dimensional vector spaces and also maps between different vector spaces. On the other hand, only complex inner product spaces are considered (no general fields $F$). Still interesting!

Here is a proof that when $f$ is linear it must be "almost orthogonal", thus the converse of orthogality-preservation is true.
Let $\bar f$ be the adjoint, i.e. for all $v,w$
$$
  \langle\bar f(v),w\rangle = \langle v,f(w)\rangle.
$$
The adjoint is well-defined because of nondegeneracy. Also because of nondegeneracy, we can rephrase orthogonality-preservation as
$$
  \forall\omega\in V^*.\forall v\in V.\:\omega(v) = 0\implies\omega(\bar f(f(v))) = 0,
$$
or in other words
$$
  \forall\omega\in V^*.\:\bar f(f(\ker\omega)) \subseteq \ker\omega.
$$
But all such $\ker\omega$ are the hyperplanes of $V$ containing $0$, so $\bar f\circ f$ must preserve all lines, i.e.
$$
  \forall v\in V.\exists\alpha\in F.\:\bar f(f(v)) = \alpha v
$$
and the only way for this to happen is if $\bar f\circ f$ is a multiple of the identity, i.e. $\alpha$ is constant. Clearly $\alpha\ne0$. It is interesting to note that if $\alpha = \beta^2$ then this also proves that $f/\beta$ is orthogonal.
We now have
$$
  \langle f(v),f(w)\rangle = 0 \implies \alpha\langle v,w\rangle = 0 \implies \langle v,w\rangle = 0.
$$

It's worth noting that if $f$ is nonlinear but still has an adjoint (I don't know if this is possible), then the same argument almost goes through. The only difference is that $\alpha$ is not constant and instead is a function $\alpha(v)$, and I'm not sure we can conclude $\alpha(v)\ne0$ for all $v$.

Many thanks for this insightful (+1) answer settling the linear case!

Would it be right to say that "$\bar{f} \circ f$ must preserve all lines" is the same as $\bar{f}=f^{-1}$?

@TedBlack No, it means it's a multiple of $f^{-1}$. The condition $\bar f = f^{-1}$ means $f$ is orthogonal, hence my comment about how if $\alpha$ is a square then $f$ is a multiple of an orthogonal map.

By "preserve" I do not mean pointwise-fix, I just mean $\bar f(f(L))\subseteq L$ for all lines $L$.
